# My doubt on Inversive Geometry with cyclic quadrilaterals

Tags: inversive-geometry

Let A , B , C be 3 points on a circle $\omega$ . let the tangents at A and at B meet at D . Let DC meets the circle again at E . Then prove that the line AE bisects BD iff AB = BC .

I have done at lot of work on it and as one might see that if I prove that right angles or if F'D = F'B then only the problem is solved but can't get it .[Image of the same is pasted here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USHcE.png)

Comment: Please help me with the problem dear MSA 's

Answer (score 0):

Let AE meets BD at F.
Let   m arcAEB = m arcBC. (1)    (m arcXYZ  is for  measure
of arc XYZ)
Let compare △DEF  with  △ADF.
∡EFD is common  (2)
m∡ADB = (m arcACB - m arcAEB) / 2   (3)
Taking into account (1), we have
m∡ADB = (m arcACB - m arcBC) / 2 = (m arcAC) / 2  (4)
m∡DEF = m∡AEC =  (m arcAC) / 2   (5)
From (4) and (5) we have
m∡ADB = m∡DEF (6)         (m∡XYZ  is for measure
of angle XYZ)
Now from (2) and (6) we have that
△DEF and △ADF are similar so we can write:
DE / AD = EF / DF = FD / FA  (7)
From (7) we have
DF² = EF * FA   (8)
But tangent secant segment theorem gives
BF² = EF * FA   (9)
From (8) and (9) we have
DF = FB,  qed.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).